# Escala de cor do Treemap com Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, rgb

Fiz um treemap utilizando o pacote `treemap`, em que a área de cada caixa está relacionada a variável `Valor` e a cor de cada caixa está relacionada a variável `escala`, que foi criada a partir da variável `Nota`. Em escala de vermelho a cinza, conforme figura abaixo:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(treemap)
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df2.csv"
df <- fread(url)
df$escala <- scale(df$Nota) 
treemap(df, index = "MUNICIPIO", vSize = "Valor", vColor = "escala",
        type = "value", palette = "-RdGy", lowerbound.cex.labels = 0.1,
        title  =  "Treemap Rio de Janeiro",
        overlap.labels=0.05)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de criar o mesmo `treemap` com o `plotly`, ou um bem parecido, de tal forma que a área das caixas estejam relacionados a variável `Valor` e a cor esteja em intensidade relacionada a variável `Nota` ou a variável `escala`. Criei o código abaixo mas não obtive sucesso. Alguém possui sugestão?

```
    color <- colorRamp(c("Red", "gray"))
colorlist <- rgb(color((df$Nota)/max(df$Nota)), max = 255)
df  %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(labels = ~ MUNICIPIO, 
                  values = ~Valor,
                  parents = ~NA,
                  type = 'treemap',
                  ids = ~Nota,
                  hovertemplate = paste0("Cidade: %{label}<extra></extra><br>",
                                         "Nota Média: %{id}")) %>%
  plotly::layout(title = "Patent scape",
                 colorway = colorlist)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente mudar a colorlist para: `rgb(color((df$Nota)/max(df$Nota)), max = max(df$Nota))`. Caso a `max(df$nota)` seja por exemplo 10. Todos os valores de cor estarão longe de 255.

Comment: @PauloMarques agradeço, mas não funcionou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui, agora vou trabalhar um pouco mais na `palette` para ficar parecido com o primeiro:

```
unique_values_count <- length(unique(df$Nota))
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("gray", "Darkred"), alpha = F)(unique_values_count)
assigned_colors <- c(palette[cut(df$Nota, unique_values_count)])
plotly::plot_ly(
  data = df,
  type = "treemap",
  labels =  ~ MUNICIPIO,
  parents = ~ NA,
  values =  ~ Valor,
  ids = ~Nota,
  marker = list(colors = assigned_colors), 
  hovertemplate = paste0("Cidade: %{label}<extra></extra><br>",
                         "Nota Média: %{id}"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

**Atualizado em 13/12/2022**

**Nota:** Não percebi que os valores não estavam em ordem. Para resolver, basta ordená-los com `sort(df$Nota, decreasing=TRUE)`

**Resposta Original modificada com o sort**

Parece que o `colorRamp` está pegando uma cor diferente para cada resultado de `df$Nota/max(df$Nota)`, o que faz sentido, pois todos os resultados são diferentes.

Usando `colorNumeric` pode resolver esta questão.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df2.csv"
df <- fread(url)

pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "Reds",
  domain = sort(df$Nota, decreasing=TRUE))

df  %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(labels = ~ MUNICIPIO, 
                  values = ~Valor,
                  parents = ~NA,
                  type = 'treemap',
                  hovertemplate = "Cidade: %{label}<extra></extra>") %>%
  plotly::layout(title = "Patent scape",
                 colorway = ~pal(sort(df$Nota, decreasing=TRUE)))
```

O resultado é

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira usar outra palette...

```
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "RdGy",
  domain = sort(df$Nota, decreasing=TRUE),
  reverse = TRUE)
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra possibilidade é usar o `colorBin` com a escala que vc definiu

```
df$escala <- scale(df$Nota) 

pal <- colorBin(
  palette = "RdGy",
  domain = sort(df$escala, decreasing=TRUE),
  reverse = TRUE,
  bins=seq(-2.5, 2.5, 0.5))

df  %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(labels = ~MUNICIPIO, 
                  values = ~Valor,
                  parents = ~NA,
                  type = 'treemap',
                  hovertemplate = "Cidade: %{label}<extra></extra>") %>%
  plotly::layout(title = "Patent scape",
                 colorway = ~pal(df$escala))
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nota:** Usei o domínio de -2.5 até 2.5, pois haviam valores fora da escala.

Comment: @fsbmat. Atualizei o post. Não havia percebido que as notas não estavam drenadas.

Comment: Oi @Paulo Marques, na verdade, não quero colorir o treemap de acordo com os valores e sim de acordo com a nota. Veja o primeiro treemap que coloquei na pergunta! Não entendi porque a resposta está, juntamente com a pergunta, com deslike?

Comment: @fsbmat, o intuito é ajudar você da melhor maneira possível e os demais que venha a cair nesta página. No entanto, tem pessoas que procuram por ajuda, não encontram e dão `dislike`, outras acham que a resposta não está correta e dão `dislike` ao invés de ajudar e corrigir a resposta, outras fazem isso sem razão, e sabe-se lá qual outra razão. Enfim, atualizei o post com o `colorBin` utilizando `df$escala` que parece que é o que você procura. Caso não seja, me desculpe por não ter entendido a demanda.

Comment: pois é, complicado o pessoal não entender o papel do like e do dislike! Agradeço muito sua ajuda, mas o resultado não é o que desejo. Se você conferir as cores e as notas, verá que o plot_ly não obedece a escala de cor. Adicionei mais um argumento no meu código que ajuda a visualizar a nota e verificar que a cor não está bem relacionada com a mesma!